# Using variable from a function outside the function

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the variables UserFirstName, UserLastName and Numpts outside this function to put them in labels. Maybe I can put them in labels directly from the function but I'm not sure what's best.
If more code is needed please ask. 
P.S I'm a beginner

```
func parseJson(_ data:Data)
{

    var actArray = [Activity]()

    do {
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]

        for jsonResult in jsonArray

        {
            let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:String]

            let act = Activity (NumUser: jsonDict["NumUser"]!, cFirstname: jsonDict["cFirstname"]!, cLastname: jsonDict["cLastname"]!, cEmail: jsonDict["cEmail"]!, cPassword: jsonDict["cPassword"]!, NumPts: jsonDict["NumPts"]!, forgotpass: jsonDict["forgotpass"]!)

            if case (act.activityContainsString(value: "allo@allo.com")) = true
                           {
                            print(act.cFirstname)
                            print(act.cLastname)
                            print(act.NumPts)
                            let UserFirstName = (act.cFirstname)
                            let UserLastName = (act.cLastname)
                            let UserNumPts = (act.NumPts)
                            }



            print (act)

            actArray.append(act)

        }
        delegate?.itemsDownloaded(activities: actArray)
       }
    catch
       {
    print("There was an error")
       }
```

}

I should be able to use my variables outside the function.

Comment: quick and fast fix use tuples and return tuples.

Answer (score 0):

outside class make one struct like this

```
     public struct UserDetails{
        let firstName: String
        let lastName: String
        let numpty: Int


         //make init method if needed for this struct

      }
```

Inside class do below things:

```
    func parseJson(_ data:Data)
    {

var actArray = [Activity]()

do {
    let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]

    for jsonResult in jsonArray

    {
        let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:String]

        let act = Activity (NumUser: jsonDict["NumUser"]!, cFirstname: jsonDict["cFirstname"]!, cLastname: jsonDict["cLastname"]!, cEmail: jsonDict["cEmail"]!, cPassword: jsonDict["cPassword"]!, NumPts: jsonDict["NumPts"]!, forgotpass: jsonDict["forgotpass"]!)

        if case (act.activityContainsString(value: "allo@allo.com")) = true
                       {
                        let data = UserDetails(firstName: act.cFirstname, lastName: act.cLastname, numpty: act.NumPts)
     //function in which I can pass data to those labels
        passDataToLabelsAndUpdate(data: data)

                        }




        actArray.append(act)

    }
    delegate?.itemsDownloaded(activities: actArray)
   }
catch
   {
print("There was an error")
   }
 }


  // this is the function which we can use to update labels
   public func passDataToLabelsAndUpdate(data: UserDetails) {
// update labels
   label.text = data.firstName
//similarly for other items
   }
```

Comment: I get "Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'HomeModel.UserDetails'" on line "passDataToLabelsAndUpdate(data: data)"

Comment: see the code changes and make sure your struct userDetails is out of any class declared as I showed above. let me know if you see any other error?